# C++ How to reuse code blocks with multiple returns (exit points)?

Tags: c++, macros, readability

I have a code block that performs a motion control procedure. Basically, it asks a servo motor to move to a certain position.

```
//code block starts

err=setVelocity(vel);
if(err!=0) return ERR_FAIL;
err=setAcceleration(acc);
if(err!=0) return ERR_FAIL;
err=setDeceleration(dec);
if(err!=0) return ERR_FAIL;
err=setPosition(pos);
if(err!=0) return ERR_FAIL;
err=startMotion();
if(err!=0) return ERR_FAIL;

//code block ends
```

And the code block is used, for example, in a homing procedure.

```
#define ERR_SUCCESS      0
#define ERR_FAIL         1

short GoHome(){

long vel,acc,dec,pos;
short err;

//Move to home
//code block starts
vel=vel1,acc=acc1,dec=dec1,pos=pos1;
...
//code block ends

//Move to offset
//code block starts
vel=vel2,acc=acc2,dec=dec2,pos=pos2;
...
//code block ends

return ERR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Every time I need this "move to" procedure, I have to copy-paste this code block with only modification on motion parameters. And the actual code block is much larger the one shown above, which is why I don't know if it's good idea to define it as a MACRO.

Actually I did define a MACRO to handle error.

```
#define IfErrThenReturn(err){  \
CString errInfo;               \
if(err!=0){                    \
    switch(err){               \
    case 0: errInfo = "Command succeeded.\n"; break;        \
    case 1: errInfo = "Command failed.\n"; break;           \
    case 2: errInfo = "Unsupported license.\n"; break;      \
    case 3: errInfo = "Parameter Error.\n"; break;          \
    ...                        \
    }                          \
    AfxMessageBox(errInfo);    \
    return EM_ERR_FAIL;        \
}                              \
```

So the code block would be like

```
//code block starts

err=setVelocity(vel);
IfErrThenReturn(err);
...

//code block ends
```

But I don't know it's wise to define the whole code block as a macro. Could someone tell me if there's other ways to improve the readability of higher level procedures like "GoHome" that utilizes the *code block*?

Comment: prefer inline functions and lambdas to macros.

Comment: why dont you put that block into a function? And that `vel`, `acc`, `dec` and `pos` smells like they belong into a struct (that you could pass to that function)

Comment: You should use exceptions for error handling.

Comment: @tobi303 Because I need to exit "GoHome", if any function in the code block returns error.

Comment: @ricecakebear thats no reason not to use a function. You can return also from the function at any time (and if needed return an additional flag to indicate success)

Comment: @tobi303 Yes, now I understand after seeing the actual code. Thanks.

Comment: **Don't drop error information** - You are the guy who turns a *"Motor 2 has no power"* into *"No work"*. Use (rich) exceptions, or at least log what you do know.

Comment: @peterchen I left that out for simplicity.  But thank you for emphasizing that. I added the logging to error handler. Is there other problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing code, it is always important to make it nice and readable, in a way that future maintenance will not have problems maintaining it. Macros do not provide a good way of keeping the code readable, due to the macro call being replaced with the macro body itself, which also can lead to misbehaviour an unexpected results.

It is easier to have it in a function:

```
#define ERR_SUCCESS      0
#define ERR_FAIL         1

bool relocate(long vel, lon acc, long dec, long pos)
{
    int err=setVelocity(vel);
    if(err!=0) {
        return false;
    }

    err=setAcceleration(acc);
    if(err!=0) {
        return false;
    }

    err=setDeceleration(dec);
    if(err!=0) {
        return false;
    }

    err=setPosition(pos);
    if(err!=0) {
        return false;
    }

    err=startMotion();
    if(err!=0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

short GoHome()
{

    //Move to home
    if(!relocate(vel1, acc1, dec1, pos1)
    {
        return ERR_FAIL;
    }

    //Move to offset
    if(!relocate(vel2, acc2, dec2, pos2)
    {
        return ERR_FAIL;
    }
    return ERR_SUCCESS;
}
```

This way there is no need to copy/paste code, have unneeded declarations of variables, and you have a function which collects all the required functionality in one place

Comment: I don't like the boolean return. It's not self-documenting. There might be different types of error returns. An enum would be better.

Comment: @FrankPuffer OP has also only `return ERR_FAIL;`

Comment: @FrankPuffer Certainly, if there is a need for more complex handling and if the caller needs to know which function failed it can be implemented. However starting from the question I felt that it is enough to see if it failed or not, but you are indeed right: For real life that should be the way to go.

Comment: @Frank Puffer Yes, you're right. As long as I call err handler inside "relocate". I could just return bool to tell the main function whether to return.

Comment: @fritzone: Actually my main point was not about handling multiple cases. Even for two cases, I would prefer an enum. It is not clear what the return value means without further information.

Comment: @FrankPuffer Yes valid point, but actually this also depends on a lot of other factors, such as on your project if they enforce this rule or not, integration into existing codebase or even just personal preference. For example errors can be handled also by throwing a special exception to indicate a special error situation, other cases have a long list of enums, numbers, etc... to signal another kind of errors, etc... For simple cases, like this (success/failure) I prefer to not to overengineer with enums, simple true/false will do (for me).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can move the code block into its own function, just you need to add a success return.

Note I don't know your types, so everything is `int` here.

```
int foo(int vel, int acc, int dec, int pos)
{
    //code block starts

    err=setVelocity(vel);
    if(err!=0) return ERR_FAIL;
    err=setAcceleration(acc);
    if(err!=0) return ERR_FAIL;
    err=setDeceleration(dec);
    if(err!=0) return ERR_FAIL;
    err=setPosition(pos);
    if(err!=0) return ERR_FAIL;
    err=startMotion();
    if(err!=0) return ERR_FAIL;

    return SUCCESS;
    //code block ends
}
```

Use

```
int result;
if ((result = foo(vel,acc,dec,pos)) != SUCCESS)
{
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That'll do. Thanks.

Comment: @ricecakebear I see you didn't accept any answer to your previous questions yet... you should accept an answer if your problem is solved. See for details about how to accept answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Not an actual answer, but something I think is relevant:

I'm somewhat opposed to using macros without a real need. Especially when tying them to C-style return flags. Might I suggest one of the following:

- Create a proper error hierarchy and throw an error
- Use assert, like `assert(setVelocity(vel) != 0);` (by the way, why is this one called *set*? Wouldn't combine assignment and error handling here, if that is the case.)
- Use at least something that is not simply an integer, like an enum class (don't like that solution myself, but better than a macro value)
- Use at least a `constexpr` instead of the macro value

But I'd really recommend one of the first two. In most parts of the code, aside from the main, I'd interpret a return as successful. Everything else should be handled by proper errors or asserts.

(I assumed that those are actually errors, if those are indeed the result that some other part uses, then by all means, go with a return value. But again, think about using an enum class.)

Comment: But the "err" is not errors of the program. But something from the motion control card, which says " the motion control card refused or was unable to execute the function". So I think it's unrelated to terminating the whole program. If I understand you point correctly.

Comment: @ricecakebear Yeah, I started somewhat on a wrong assumption, I guess. Still, in that case, go with enum class.

Comment: @Aziuth: Don't have side effects in `assert` as `assert(setVelocity(vel) != 0)`. Else release build (with `NDEBUG` set) won't behave as expected.

Comment: @Jarod42 Not sure what setVelocity does, if it has side effects, sure. I find it somewhat strange to have a setter (?) that seems to return (?) some value in the first place - would rather get rid of that side effect than of the assert and do what is now the side effect as a separate step.

Answer (score 0):

Only use the processor when there is no possibility within C/C++

Your case could rewritten like

```
#define ERR_SUCCESS      0
#define ERR_FAIL         1

bool move(long vel, long acc, long dec, long pos)
{
  return 
    (0 == setVelocity(vel)) &&
    (0 == setAcceleration(acc)) &&
    (0 == setDeceleration(dec)) &&
    (0 == setPosition(pos)) &&
    (0 == startMotion());
}

short GoHome() {

//Move to home
   if (! move(vel1,acc1,dec1,pos1)) return ERR_FAIL;

//Move to offset
   if (! move(vel2,acc2,dec2,pos2)) return ERR_FAIL;

   return ERR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create helper functions:

```
enum class ErrorStatus { Fail, Success };

ErrorStatus DoJobs(std::initializer_list<std::function<ErrorStatus()>> actions)
{
    for (auto&& action : actions) {
        auto err = action();
        if (err != ErrorStatus::Success) {
            return err;
        }
    }
    return ErrorStatus::Success;
 }

ErrorStatus relocate(long vel, long acc, long dec, long pos)
{
    return DoJobs( {
        [&](){ return setVelocity(vel); },
        [&](){ return setAcceleration(acc); },
        [&](){ return setDeceleration(dec); },
        [&](){ return setPosition(pos); },
        [](){ return startMotion(); }});
}
```

And finally:

```
ErrorStatus GoHome(){
    return DoJobs( {
        [](){return relocate(vel1, acc1, dec1, pos1); },
        [](){return relocate(vel2, acc2, dec2, pos2); }
    });
}
```